# What do I need to whitelist to allow Call of Duty: Black Ops 3 to connect to servers?

Tags: technical-issues, networking, call-of-duty-black-ops-3

Call of Duty: Black Ops 3 servers are being blocked, I cannot play online at all. My Internet filter is my main suspect. I have set up port forwarding through my router and the same issue is still happening.

What address do I add to my Internet Filter whitelist to stop this from happening? Unfortunately I cannot just simply allow a particular application to have access to all connections through my filter. If I add the server address to the whitelist, I can stop my filter from blocking it, but adding Black Ops 3 to the whitelist would be so much easier.

I'm not on a university campus. I have not tried disabling my filter.

Can someone tell me what it is that I have to allow? I have asked this on a lot of different places with absolutely no response.

Comment: Have you tried turning off your internet filter to ensure that's actually the issue?

Comment: At the time I made this post, @Frank, The filter was my main suspect, and it still is. I have set up port forwarding through my router and the same issue is still happening.

Comment: Well, you should probably confirm that it's the issue by testing connections with it disabled.  If you still can't connect, then it's not the problem.

Comment: *[Comments cleaned up and clarifications incorporated into question]*

Answer (score 1):

It would be helpful to know what kind of firewall is blocking your traffic in order to get more specific answers.
Anyway, you can't just whitelist all CoD IPs. There are simply too many possibilities and you'll have a hard time figuring them out. And even then it's not guaranteed to work, because the ports required are probably still closed.

It is common practice to set up **port forwarding**.
For CoD that would be the **port 3074** (TCP and UDP). For multiple devices on your network you can as well forward ports 3075, 3076,... for those (for best results, if you're playing at the same time).

If you're just using a Windows firewall with too strict rules you can simply whitelist the game executables there.

Activision has a pretty good [knowledge base](https://support.activision.com/articles/en_US/FAQ/Port-Forward-and-NAT-FAQ) about all this.

Comment: Set up some port forwarding rules within my router...

Port 3074 - (MY PC) - UDP

Port 3074 - (MY PC) - TCP

Port 3075 - (MY PC) - UDP

Port 3075 - (MY PC) - TCP

and no dice. Am I doing anything wrong?

Comment: @Kirbyman13 looks like we need more info about your network then. Are there any firewalls, proxies, special access points? Is it your own home network? etc.

Comment: It is my own home network, @dly. I do have a proxy for my internet filter, which is why I was concerned and thought this was the main issue here. I have the standard Windows Firewall and have checked all of the rules through there, nothing fishy.

Comment: @Kirbyman13 the proxy will be the issue. Depending on what kind of proxy you have you'll have to divert CoD traffic to the proxy or set up the proxy to let it right through... or disable/bypass it completely for playing games.

Comment: that's the main problem. I can't directly configure my proxy from my computer, I go through a site. Furthermore, it isn't listed under a list of proxies, instead, it is under task manager as "CovenantEyesProxy.exe." On the site, you can't whitelist an app, the only option you have is to whitelist specific URLs. Is it possible for me to setup some sort of a wildcard URL to allow all IPs on port 3074?

Comment: @Kirbyman13 that depends on your proxy. Just give it a try and look for such an option.

Comment: I've searched and navigated the site and the only filtration option you have is to add URL's to the whitelist. I tried doing *:3074 as a sort of wildcard IP but no luck.

Answer (score 1):

Hey everyone :) I found a solution!

I emailed a representative for my filtering service for the last few days and have found a solution! By uninstalling my filter and downloading an experimental version from a hidden customersupport account, I was able to get my filter from blocking CoD. :) Cheers!